# Unable to specify alterntive credentials using 802.1x wireless connections on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, certificate, wifi, credentials, 802.1

Using Windows 7 I am unable to connect to the wireless network using 802.1x settings. I have configured it exactly as in Vista using certificates and checking the use alternative credentials check box - however it just prompts for domain username each time and won't let me specify an different username.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please change one of the tags to a windows7 tag, maybe the security tag.

Comment: Make sure you entered the network SID in the proper case. If it's wrong, delete the connection and re-create it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue for my school network connection and followed the steps that were given on the school's website. I would recommend you contact your network administrator to get the details of the wireless connection and follow the steps shown in the link below to change the alternative login credentials.. Hope it helps..

http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/cs/chip/howtodoc/dot1x_files/dot1x-Win7.htm

Tarun

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using smart card based logins. it needs to be mschap v2